# Yii 1.1 transactions sync between requests

Tags: php, yii, transactions

Here is an example code, that I run:

```
public function actionTestLocks3()
{
    $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $loan = Loan::model()->findByPk(1);
        $loan->col1 = "test3";
        sleep(10);
        $loan->save()
        $transaction->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
        throw($e);
        // other actions to perform on fail (redirect, alert, etc.)
    }
    echo 'done';
}

public function actionTestLocks4()
{
    $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $loan = Loan::model()->findByPk(1);
        $loan->col2 = "test4";
        $loan->save();
        $transaction->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
        throw($e);
    }
    echo 'done';
}
```

I have two actions and I run them same with a very small interval(~1 second). First I run TestLocks3 then I run TestLocks4.
Now, what I expect to see? Ofcourse I want to see Loan model having col2=test4 and col1=test3, however what I get is col1=test3 and col2=old value. So for me it tells that transaction did not work.

If I select model in a different way, findBySql with addition of 'SELECT ... FOR UPDATE' then transaction between two requests works just fine and testLocks4() waits testLocks3() to finish and save model info.

Can you explain me either or 
how to use findByPk with 'select ... for' option
or how to make transaction work without it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your approach and got exactly the result you expected. I used MySQL and InnoDB.

Did you verify that your Database supports transactions? Yii won't tell you that transactions are not supported, for instance if you are using MYISAM-Tables.

Note that there is a semicolon missing after $loan->save() in your code.

Comment: thank you, for checking this.
Can I ask you, which version of Yii, do you use.
I use Yii 1 ... 
Big difference between Yii1 and Yii2 is that in Yii2 they have mechanism implemented in model->save() method, to save only changed fields.

Comment: I used MySQL and InnoDB as well. So It is still unclear for me, what is in the root of bug then...

Comment: Did you check if the validation of the $loan model was successful? Maybe like this: var_dump($loan->getErrors ()); after the call of $loan->save ();